# Postgres update Query works in pgAdmin but fails from Java

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, pgadmin

Below is  my query which works fine in pgAdmin

```
UPDATE data SET data = data - 'dateAdded' || '{"dateAdded":1481500800000}' 
WHERE dtype='Customer' and data->>'id' = '00784591'
```

The same query throws an error from my Spring Boot application.Below is the error:

```
StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE data SET
data = data - 'dateAdded' || '{"dateAdded":1481500800000}'
WHERE dtype='Customer' and data->>'id' = '00784591']; SQL state [S0001];
error code [102]; Incorrect syntax near '|'.; nested exception is
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 
'|'.
```

Please note that I am running other select queries too from my application and they work fine. Its just this one that fails. I am using jdbcTemplate and calling update method on jdbcTemplate to run this query. Can you point out the issue?

Comment: Maybe you have to escape the `|`'s with backslash? `\|\|`

Comment: PgAdmin is a tool to deal with PostgreSQL databases. com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException is an exception thrown by a JDQC driver for the SQLServer database. Why do you expect SQLServer to accept any SQL query accepted by PostgreSQL. They are different databases, with different features.

Comment: Oh yes, I am using two data source configuration files, I think it picked the wrong data source configuration for this query. I will check my code once and update it accordingly. Thanks for pointing out. My bad . Will post here whatever happens.

Comment: Yes, as you pointed out, it was my mistake, I was using the sqlserver datasource configuration for this query. I changed it and it worked. I am sorry for my mistake. Thanks again.